# Simple byte de/compression with standard libary needed

Tags: c++, compression

I know that there are several questions close to this one but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

I am looking for a simple byte compression method in c++. It is very important for me to keep the application size to a minimum, so I want to use a library which is available in every windows version (starting from xp and up). I don't want to use .net or add large .dll's to my app.

I'm more interested in speed and small size than compression rate.

Can anyone help me with this one? I just switched from vb.net to c++ so I am quite new to this language :)

Comment: Look up Byte Pair Encoding, but I don't think it's in any standard library. The encoder/compressor and decoder/decompressor are tiny and fast, you can simply include their code in your app.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze This was my first idea when I was thinking about writing my own compression function. But it looks like this is only efficient for text compression. Do you have any information about the compression ratio for data?

Comment: Compression depends a lot on data. I've got some executables and source code files compressed down to 30 to 50 % of the original. You can also tune compression by manipulating with BLOCKSIZE, HASHSIZE, MAXCHARS, THRESHOLD (I'm referring to the code by Philip Gage described in Dr.Dobb's).

Comment: Speaking about simple and small, did you tried LZ4 ? http://code.google.com/p/lz4/

Answer (score 0):

IHave a look at [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). I'm happy with this library.

Comment: I've come across this library very often during my research. However, I'm am having difficulties implementing it in my application. I have been using vb.net's gzipstream for compression. I have read that it is possible to decompress this data with zlib. Still, I haven't yet figured out how. Even though I include zlib.h I can't figure out what function I have to use. Can you provide me with more information or even a small example?
Also, how many kb's does zlib add to my application, can you give an approximate number?

Comment: I don't know how much code will be linked into your application. You need to try and see for yourself. The usage example on the zlib's website is neat: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Comment: @Lotzki Be advised that gzip and zlib are similar but not exactly interchangeable. However, data coming out of something called gzipstream ought be be decompressable by zlib functions (if you find the right ones). Don't be shy about asking more specific questions about zlib usage, especially since at least one of the authors hangs out on Stack Overflow.